# gulp tasks - concatenate files that created by another gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

I want to minify my `js` files in my `/_dev` folder then rename them and copy hem to `minify-js` folder, then concatenate minified files.

I use a `gulpfile.js` like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
rename = require('gulp-rename'),
concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('minify-js', function() {
        return gulp.src('_dev/js/libraries/*.js')
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(rename({
                suffix: '.min'
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('minifiedJS'));
});

gulp.task('concatFiles',['minify-js'],function (){
     return gulp.src(['minifiedJS/jquery.jplayer.min.js', 'minifiedJS/jplayer.playlist.min.js', 'minifiedJS/LinkToPlayer.min.js'])
         .pipe(concat('final.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_dist/js'));
});
```

when I run:

```
gulp concatFiles
```

minify-js task create the following file in `minifiedJS`folder.

```
jquery.jplayer.min.js
jplayer.playlist.min.js
LinkToPlayer.min.js
```

but `final.js` won't create till I run `gulp concatFiles` command again.

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Why you are doing this in separate task while you may do both part in single task

Comment: because i Thought that making this task sequential force the concat task to run after minified file creation.
do you know a way that it works just in one task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try in one task as following

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('minify-js', function(){
    return gulp.src('_dev/js/libraries/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('concat.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(rename('final.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['minify-js'], function(){});
```

Comment: oh, you mean I should first concatenate then uglify them, good choice, thanks